# What is logic build in When we want to Status should not blank

Tags: after-trigger

What I use when the Picklist value should not blank in trigger?

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your question please? String.IsNotBlank() comes to mind but there may be a better solution given the detail...

Answer (score 1):

You can use null check like

> if(Status__c != null)